# Apollo server playground not working on heroku (Working Locally)

Tags: node.js, heroku, ecmascript-6, apollo-server

I am Trying to deploy run node js application on heroku, it is deployed successfully but playground doesn't seems to work.

I came around this solution by setting `introspection: true`: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1718 but that also doesn't seems to work.

heroku logs

[image: heroku logs]

My code:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "travelindiaserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "clean": "rm -rf build && mkdir build",
    "build-babel": "babel -d ./build ./src -s",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-babel",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./build/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.4.8",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "graphql": "^14.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import express from "express";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";

import typeDefs from "./schema";
import resolvers from "./resolvers";
import models from "./models";

const app = express();

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: { models },
  introspection: true
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(
    ` Server ready at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`
  )
);
```

models/index.js

```
const cities = [{ name: "City 1" }, { name: "City 2" }];

export default {
  cities
};
```

resolvers/cityResolvers.js

```
export default {
  Query: {
    cities: (parent, args, { models }) => {
      return models.cities;
    }
  }
};
```

resolvers/index.js

```
import cityResolvers from "./cityResolvers";

export default [cityResolvers];
```

schema/city.js

```
import { gql } from "apollo-server-express";

export default gql`
  extend type Query {
    cities: [City]
  }

  type City {
    name: String
  }
`;
```

schema/index.js

```
import { gql } from "apollo-server-express";

import citySchema from "./city";

const linkSchema = gql`
  type Query {
    _: Boolean
  }

  type Mutation {
    _: Boolean
  }

  type Subscription {
    _: Boolean
  }
`;

export default [linkSchema, citySchema];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, Apollo server turns off introspection and playground when running with `NODE_ENV=production`. Since Heroku sets it by default when you use the `node buildpack` your playground is disabled.

To circumvent the issue you need to pass to apollo-server 2 options:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  introspection: true,
  playground: true
});
```